# Confused about @Inject

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm really confused about the @Inject in Java.  I've read about CDI in the Java EE tutorial, and I still don't get it.  Would you take a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
package model.businessLayer;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import model.domainLayer.RADplusUserSupplemental;

@Named(value = "staffLocal")
public class StaffCaseloadMgr implements StaffCaseloadMgrLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CareTeamPersist")
    EntityManager em;

    public StaffCaseloadMgr() {}

    /**
     * Returns the list of user supplemental records from the database,
     * based on the patid passed in to staff caseload.
     * @param patid The patient, or consumer ID
     * @return List of RADplusUserSupplemental records
     */
    public List<RADplusUserSupplemental> getListForEmails(String patid) {
        return em.createNamedQuery("StaffCaseload.findEmails",
            RADplusUserSupplemental.class)
            .getResultList();
    }
}
```

I put the constructor in there, thinking it might help.  I'm not sure why it would, though, seeing as how it's the default constructor.  Okay, next.

```
package utils;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import model.businessLayer.StaffCaseloadMgr;
import model.domainLayer.RADplusUserSupplemental;

@SessionScoped
public class CareTeam implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    static StaffCaseloadMgr staffLocal;

    /**
     * This is a static method that retrieves the care team given a particular
     * consumer ID.
     * 
     * @param consumerID
     *            The consumer ID for which to get the care team
     * 
     * @return A list of emails for the care team
     */
    public static List<Map<String, String>> getCareTeamEmails(String consumerID) {

        List<Map<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (RADplusUserSupplemental userSupp : staffLocal
                .getListForEmails(consumerID)) {
            Map<String, String> emailMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            emailMap.put("staffEmail", userSupp.getOrganizationEmailAddress());
            arrayList.add(emailMap);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

}
```

I'm using Maven, so I put an empty `beans.xml` in `resources/META-INF`.  I'm very confused about why it's not working.  Can you help?

I should have known you couldn't read my mind!  Sorry about that.  I'm using a JBoss container, and my `application.xml` has version 7 in it.  I want to put my JPA in a separate .jar file, because this little function is going to used by several different processes.

The stack trace looks like this:

```
07:58:00,811 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/TestConfiguration-1.0].[rest]] (http-/172.29.8.11:443-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet rest threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at utils.CareTeam.getCareTeamEmails(CareTeam.java:43) [CareTeam-1.0.0.jar:]
    at controller.TestConfiguration.testing(TestConfiguration.java:33) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

EDIT 2:
So I took Svetlin's advice and got rid of the "static" in front of the variable.  I'm having to call another class which has the @Inject in it, like so:

CareTeam.java

```
package utils;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CareTeam implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * This is a static method that retrieves the care team given a particular
     * consumer ID.
     * 
     * @param consumerID
     *            The consumer ID for which to get the care team
     * 
     * @return A list of emails for the care team
     */
    public static List<Map<String, String>> getCareTeamEmails(String consumerID) {
        CareTeamImpl careTeam = new CareTeamImpl();
        return careTeam.getCareTeamEmails(consumerID);
    }

}
```

CareTeamImpl.java

```
package utils;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import model.businessLayer.StaffCaseloadMgr;
import model.domainLayer.RADplusUserSupplemental;

@SessionScoped
public class CareTeamImpl implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    StaffCaseloadMgr staffLocal;

    /**
     * This is a static method that retrieves the care team given a particular
     * consumer ID.
     * 
     * @param consumerID
     *            The consumer ID for which to get the care team
     * 
     * @return A list of emails for the care team
     */
    public List<Map<String, String>> getCareTeamEmails(String consumerID) {

        List<Map<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (RADplusUserSupplemental userSupp : staffLocal
            .getListForEmails(consumerID)) {
            Map<String, String> emailMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            emailMap.put("staffEmail", userSupp.getOrganizationEmailAddress());
            arrayList.add(emailMap);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

}
```

It still isn't working.  It's failing on the deployment, with this:

```
11:49:45,624 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-18) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."TestConfiguration-1.0.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."TestConfiguration-1.0.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnserializableDependencyException: WELD-001413 The bean Managed Bean [class utils.CareTeamImpl] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declares passivating scope but has non-serializable dependency Managed Bean [class model.businessLayer.StaffCaseloadMgr] with qualifiers [@Any @Default @Named]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointPassivationCapable(Validator.java:360)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:331)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:280)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:382)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:367)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:64)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    ... 3 more
```

I wasn't doing the "implements Serializable" thing in CareTeam.java - I looked at a thing in RedHat Customer Portal which recommended on this type of error to make it Serializable - so I put that in there and got the same result.  Now I don't know what to think.

Comment: We are confused more than you; at least you know what's not working, we don't (you keep it as a secret for some reason).

Comment: Sorry about that - I should have known that you couldn't read my mind! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject into a static field: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-51